# jquery tabs postback problem

Tags: jquery, tabs

i am using jquery library in my project.I have terrible problem with jquery tabs.Solutions is that when i was in  third tab,i post back my form,tabs reloaded and goes to first tab.
i am searching to solve problem long time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example > ul").tabs({ remote: true, cache: true });
    });       
</script>
```

so how i solve this problem?
thx your answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tabs can use cookies to store the current tab. Have a look at the tabs [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Tabs). Down in the Options list there is an example of how to use cookies to store the current tab:

```
$('.selector').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```

This requires the [jquery cookies plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) to be included though.

Comment: For me this was the best and easiest solution to implement. I have many tabs on three different pages and the tabs maintain their state across tab clicks and page postbacks. Awesome.

Comment: Ahh, this looks like a perfect solution to a problem I'm having with partial views in tabs... unfortunately, the jquery web site was taken down due to ad spammer attacks, to the links to the tabs documentation and jquery cookies plugin are now unavailable...

Answer (score 24):

You didn't specify if you're using ASP.NET, but if you are you can store the currently selected tab in an <asp:HiddenField /> instead of a cookie:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#example").tabs({
            show: function() {
                var sel = $('#example').tabs('option', 'selected');
                $("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val(sel);
            },
            selected: <%= hidLastTab.Value %>
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidLastTab" Value="0" />
```

If not ASP.NET, you could probably do something similar.

Comment: I tried many other solutions unsuccessfully. This one worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to use the solution posted by joelsand. However, the jQuery Tabs options and events have changed. The current documentation is at http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/.

Instead of the "show" event, I used the "activated" event.
Instead of the "selected" option, I used the "active" option.
Instead of a hidden field, I used a JavaScript variable (declared outside the UpdatePanel)

Comment: Event name is **activate** (not "activated").

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed by adding the following to the jquery tabs select event handler:

```
$("div.ui-tabs-panel").html("");
```

It effectively clears all existing panels to prevent form stacking.