# Hidden Field not maintaining values across prostback?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-tabs, hidden-field

I am using `jquery ui` `tabs`.While using the tabs i came across a scenario where, druing postback the tab is not maintaing the selected index.I searched it and found out the solution.My problem is the value in the hidden field is set to null during postback and as a result selected index cannot be maintained during postback in `jquery ui` `tabs`.

How can i solve this issue?

Heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){        

    //maintaining selected tab during postback    
        var selectedIndex=$("#<%=hFieldTabIndex.ClientID %>").val();
        alert(selectedIndex)//here value is always set to null
        if(selectedIndex==""){
            $("#tabs").tabs({active:0});
        }
        else{
             $("#tabs").tabs({active:1});
        }

    //Change the text of the button on tab change    
        $("#tabs").on("tabsactivate",function(){
           var index=$("#tabs").tabs("option","active");
           $("#<%=hFieldTabIndex.ClientID %>").val(index);//setting the hiddenfield value
           alert($("#<%=hFieldTabIndex.ClientID %>").val());//showing currect tab index
           if(index=="0"){
                $("#btnNext").attr('value','Next>>')
            }
           else{
                $("#btnNext").attr('value','<<Prev')
            }
        })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600089/jquery-tabs-postback-problem). Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#example").tabs({
        show: function() {
            var sel = $('#example').tabs('option', 'selected');
            $("#<%= hidLastTab.ClientID %>").val(sel);
        },
        selected: <%= hidLastTab.Value %>
    });
});
```

If it is not working then try to use a script global variable like `var tabNo=0;` and set and get values same as you are using with hidden field.

Comment: i dont know why hidden value is set to null.The above also not working

Comment: Sorry for the late response.How can i use global variable?Can you show with an example?Will the value stored in the global variable be maintained across postback.

Answer (score 0):

finally got the solution i have written some code in the page load to store the value of hiddenfield .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hFieldTabIndex.Value = Request.Form[hFieldTabIndex.UniqueID];
}
```